# converted desktop bridge applications and account type

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I just finally converted a free desktop win32 windows application that I've developed in order to submit it in the windows 10 store.

Following these instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion
I was finally able to create the package and install it on my machine. Everything works perfectly. So I thought I was ready to submit it on the store.

However, when I try to submit it on the Microsoft developer dashboard i get these errors:

Package acceptance validation error: You don't have permissions to specify the following namespaces in the appx manifest file of the package SpeedyPainter.appx: restricted namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities
Package acceptance validation error: Your developer account doesn’t have permission to submit apps converted with the Desktop Bridge at this time. https://aka.ms/desktopbridgeforwindowsstore

I have an individual developer account. Maybe the reason of the failure in the submission process is due to type of my account? Maybe only company accounts can post desktop bridge converted apps, even if an app is free?

Thank you in advance!
kind regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in [this form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) first. Then related team who then review it can make sure it has all of the information and once that information is verified then they move forwards having it assigned out and have the developer contacted to be worked with.

The process could take a couple of business days. If you don't receive response from it, please create a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account.

Comment: thank you for the very useful suggestion. After doing what you suggested, now I am being followed by the Desktop Bridge team that is really kind and is giving an amazing support. After some verifications they finally unlocked my account to be able to upload my appx. Now I still have to fix some certification issues, but those are depending on my app, not on the upload process. Thank you